# Deserializing into Map<java.lang.String, java.net.URI> with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, uri

I have this JSON snippet:

```
{
"uploadData": {
    "25967391": {
        "jobid": "jobId",
        "numberOfFiles": "1",
        "outputFiles": {
            "1": "file.pdf"
        },
        "originalFiles": {
            "1": "./target/test-classes/com/tools/myProject/input/File.pdf",
            "2": "./target/test-classes/com/tools/myProject/input/File.csv"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to deserialize "originalFiles" into a Map. Because "1" and "2" in "originalFiles" are both non absolute URIs I already have a custom class `URIStringDeserializer` which does

```
Paths.get(".").toUri().resolve(uriString).normalize().toASCIIString()
```

which gives me

```
file:/C:/Users/userName/IdeaProjects/myProject/target/test-classes/com/tools/myProject/input/File.pdf
```

for the first uri of the `originalFiles`.
Here is the class with `uploadData` field:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UploadData{

 @JsonProperty("originalFiles")
 private Map<Integer, URI> originalFiles;

 //getters and setters omitted
}
```

Annotating the `uploadData` field with `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)` results in a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.net.URI out of START_OBJECT token`. How can I get my custom deserializer working with tose map?

Comment: may be your map json is not correct. Can you try this ?

 "originalFiles": {
        "1": { 
               "./target/test-classes/com/tools/myProject/input/File.pdf"
             },
        "2": {
               "./target/test-classes/com/tools/myProject/input/File.csv"
             }
        }

Comment: This JSON snippet is only a part of a bigger JSON, I copied it for questioning purposes. The whole part is valid according to JSONLint. Thanks for pointing. I updated the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extern help the solution was found. Adding

```
@JsonDeserializer(contentUsing = CustomDeserializer.class)
```

has done what I wanted.